# Why can't I see any HD option when uploading a video to Youtube?

Tags: youtube

I've recorded a 5-minute video on my Android phone. It is 1920x1080 and about 1.5Gb. I just spent nearly an hour uploading this to YouTube and when it finished, the only quality setting available was 360p.

I've removed it and gone to try again but I can see no option anywhere about the upload quality setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes a while until all resolutions are processed, especially with huge files such as yours. When waiting for a couple of hours or days, additional resolutions should get fully processed.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try uploading a shorter HD video (possibly 1 minute or less) and see if HD option is available. Also, please check Youtube's help as your first effort.